# Develop a phonegap application, Is there a plugin for netbeans?

Tags: cordova, netbeans-plugins

I have been looking for a netbeans plugin for phoneGap (Cordova) [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/) but I didn't find anything.

1. How to develop in phoneGap using netbeans?
2. Is it there a plugin to install ? and
3. Where find phonegap plugin for netbeans?

Comment: Phonegap development is just HTML, CSS and JS. You don't need a plugin for that. If you are writing Phonegap plugins you will need IDEs from the platforms you are building for, but standard PhoneGap development does not require any specific IDE or IDE integration.

Comment: Thannk you @DawsonLoudon but you need the plugin and it exists: See  my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Search for the Cordova PlugIn

[image]

Accept the term and Install

[image: Search for the Cordova PlugIn]

Enjoy PhoneGap in Netbeans
[image: Using PhoneGap]

Comment: Interesting, what does it do? I use the CLI for creating and building, maybe it just runs that from within netbeans?